# Basic Instapot Operation - setting the cooking time under Manual/Pressure Cook button

Tags: pressure-cooker

Plug in the instapot - display shows OFF. Then press Pressure Cook (Manual) button, the timer shows a minute or so. Press "+" button and timer increments by seconds, up to 4 minutes then resets to zero and counts up again. Cant't set to my desired cook time - say 10 min. What am i missing?

Answer (score 4):

> timer increments by seconds, up to 4 minutes then resets to zero

The most probable case is that you are misreading the label. It probably shows minutes, increments up to 4 hours, then resets to zero.

My Instant Pot is an older IP-Duo model, and its display is in minutes only, so above 60, it just goes 61, 62, etc., not 1:01, 1:02. But it still resets after 240.

Different Instant Pot models have different programs, but I doubt that anybody made a program counting down in seconds, since that precision is not needed in pressure cooking. When combined with the info that they are already restricting my model at 4 hours (which makes sense too, for recipes longer than that, you probably don't want the pressure cooking mode anyway), I would say you are just assuming the wrong unit.

Comment: Correct - Instant Pots operate in hours:minutes, not minutes:seconds (which is the standard for microwaves, that may explain the confusion).